# Is there a way to check if an element is boolean in prolog?

Tags: prolog

For example in scheme there is the function "boolean?" which checks if an element is boolean.

Comment: What is a boolean? There is no (standardized) definition for "boolean".

Comment: Also could you provide an example?

Comment: For example, I need to build a data type that is a list of Booleans, but first I need to verify if the elements that are going to make up that list are Boolean.In prolog there is "number" that returns True if Term is bound to a rational number. So what I'm looking for is something similar that works with booleans.

Comment: @NicolásSalgadoMatus: well the question is: how do you *represent* booleans. Constants are simply constants, a constant `true/0` has no "special meaning".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what I'm trying to say is that I need to verify if an elemment of any type is a boolean. The elemment can be a string or a number.

Comment: @NicolásSalgadoMatus: but there does not exists a type boolean. What values would be booleans? See https://www.swi-prolog.org/datatypes.html

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ok I understand you. So if I need to use true/0 or false/0 I will use what you wrote in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping me @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no standardized values for true and false (in contrast to a list). We can however use `true/0` and `false/0`, and thus use:

```
boolean(true).
boolean(false).
```

or check this without unification with:

```
is_boolean(X) :-
    X == true;
    X == false.
```

Comment: An interesting detail: `true` and `false` are atoms, but they are also system-provided zero-ary predicates so `true` and `false` are mapped to `true/0` and `false/0` when they appear in predicate position. (In SWI-Prolog you additionally have `true()` and `false()`, compound terms of arity 0, but mapped to the expected predicates.  Now ... would one say _"We can however use `true/0` and `false/0`"_ or _"We can however use `true` and `false`"_?

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum, the predicate [`must_be/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=must_be/2) (SWI-Prolog only?) is as good as it gets in deciding whether something is a boolean:

```
?- must_be(boolean,true).
true.

?- must_be(boolean,false).
true.

?- must_be(boolean,foo).
ERROR: Type error: `boolean' expected, found `foo' (an atom)
```

Both `true` and `false` are just atoms:

```
?- atom(true).
true.

?- atom(false).
true.
```

(Even [Mercury](https://mercurylang.org/information/doc-release/mercury_ref/Primitive-types.html#Primitive-types) doesn't have a dedicated "boolean" type.)

*However*, you can actually *call* the atoms `true` and `false`, whereby they are interpreted as 0-ary predicates and perform as expected, either succeeding the query or failing the query (that would be called "de-reifying the truth value", eh?)

```
?- true.
true.

?- false.
false.
```